# If I'm playing Diablo 3 without a mouse can I Identify items?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I'm playing Diablo 3 without a mouse, how can I Identify items?

Comment: How are you playing Diablo 3 without a mouse? I thought it wasn't possible to map movement to keys...?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to play it without a mouse, you could use mouse keys, or a drawing pad, but they still have the option for a right click.

Comment: Is this question really going to be useful to 99.9% of the D3 players out there?

Comment: Wait, questions have to be useful to 99.9% of players to be acceptable?

Comment: Give them to me if they are iLvl 61 or higher, I'll identify them ;)

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you have activated [Mouse Keys](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Use-Mouse-Keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer) in the Accessibility Center.

The mouse emulation works on the principle, that there are two mouse buttons and only *one* can be the active button at a given time.

The three upper right keys, <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>, are used to control the selection:

- <kbd>/</kbd> (forward-slash) to select left mouse button.
- <kbd>-</kbd> (minus) key to select the right button.
- <kbd>*</kbd> (star, multiplication) key to select *both* buttons.

Pressing <kbd>5</kbd> presses the curently selected mouse button.

So, in your case, move over the item with the arrow keys, press -, and then 5 to identify the item.

Just tested this, it works in D3 (and most probably, in any game or application, too).

The menu key, which on desktop simulates the right button, does not work in Diablo 3 as a right button action.

This should work similarly on MacOS X.

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing on a Windows machine using a standard keyboard there should be a "Menu Key" that looks like an arrow hovering over a menu - that emulates a Right click on your mouse.

If you're playing with a gamepad then the alternative keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> so use that as a custom keybind.

(Untested in Diablo 3 so have your grain of salt ready)

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing on a Mac using the touch pad, you have two options: you can use command-click to simulate a right click, or you can enable the two-finger right click in the options for your touch pad, in which case clicking with two fingers contacting the touch pad will give you a right click.

Comment: or you can enable clicking in the right corner for right click